# Can I replicate data between mySQL and SQL Server/SQL Azure?

Tags: sql-server, mysql, amazon-ec2, replication, azure

I have a replicated mySQL setup running happily on Amazon AWS, making user data available locally in various regions.  Now I'm faced with an app that needs to go up on Microsoft Azure and I need to replicate the data over to there as well.

So that's annoying. I am faced with several options:

1. Replicate from mySQL to SQL Azure/SQL Server seems like it would be lovely - is this possible?  I'd consider using a third party tool and paying $$ if I had to.  We're not using anything complicated in the db feature set, it's just data in tables.
2. Get mySQL working on Microsoft Azure - which seems really dicey at best.  All the HOWTOs I can find say "this is possible but you really shouldn't try this for production apps."
3. Go non-realtime and do syncs from mySQL to SQL Azure, which may be somewhat expensive and slower.
4. Rip out all my mySQL on Amazon and use SQL Server there, which would make Baby Jesus cry.

Has anyone gotten mySQL to SQL Azure/SQL Server replication or syncing working?  Or have any other approaches (a NoSQL solution that replicates and might meet our but-we-need-to-join-some-tables needs that can easily be run on Amazon and Azure)?

Comment: See also: [Transferring data between SQL Server and MySQL](http://serverfault.com/questions/24625/transferring-data-between-sql-server-and-mysql/608113#608113)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this will help, but here's a good article on how to use Azure and its SQL Azure from MySQL:

http://whitepages.sfintelligence.com/2011/01/setting-up-wordpress-on-windows-and-sql-azure-a-walkthrough/

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks, though the problem is I need to replicate between whatever I'm using on Azure and my mySQL instances on Amazon. So if, as this article talks about, I convert from mySQL to SQL Azure on Azure, I don't have a way to replicate...

Answer (score 0):

> SQL Server Migration Assistant (SSMA) for MySQL lets you quickly
>   convert MySQL database schemas to SQL Server or SQL Azure schemas,
>   upload the resulting schemas into SQL Server or SQL Azure, and migrate
>   data from MySQL to SQL Server or SQL Azure.

You can use this small app and guide on msdn. Get started [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh313129%28v=sql.110%29.aspx) : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh313129%28v=sql.110%29.aspx

It is answered here too : 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16584311/import-mysql-db-into-ms-azure